# Exception in Great Picard

Tags: complex-analysis

Recently I learned about the Great Picard Theorem, which says that

> If an analytic function f has an essential singularity at a point w, then on any punctured neighborhood of w, f(z) takes on all possible complex values, with at most a single exception, infinitely often. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem)

I am wondering: regarding the "one exception" that perhaps exists, does the theorem think of a value that is attained finitely many times as a potential exception? In other words, does the theorem say that in a punctured neighborhood of an essential singularity, a complex value is either attained infinitely often or never attained?

I'm not familiar with a proof of Great Picard's theorem. Maybe this would be clarified if I read a proof.

Comment: An exception may never be obtained as a value e.g. $e^\frac{1}{z}$ has an essential singularity in $0$, but is never $0$

Comment: To continue this:
Considering $f(z) = (1 - z) e^{1 / z}$. Then in the punctured ball of radius $2$, $f$ of course takes on the value $0$ but not infinitely often.